# how to retrieve caller function js file global variable value in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Sample Code from nodejs:

Code from JS1.js :

```
var js2=require("../../util");
var dataName="Billy";
function hello1(){
   js2.hello2("message");
}
```

Code from JS3.js :

```
var js2=require("../../util");
var dataName="Tom";
function hello3(){
   js2.hello2("message");
}
```

Code from JS2.js :

```
exports.hello2=hello2;
function hello2(arg1){
   console.log(arg1);
   //Here I need the data in global variable "dataName" of file JS1.js or JS3.js
}
```

I need to access the global variable of caller js file.

Answer (score 1):

All modules share a `global` object in node.js.  So in JS1.js ...

```
global.dataName = "Billy";
```

... then in JS2.js:

```
console.log(global.dataName);
```

However, it shouldn't be surprising that using `global` in this way is generally considered poor form.  Unless you have a specific reason for not wanting JS2 to depend on JS1, it's probably better to just have JS2 export `dataName` as part of it's `module.exports`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I made some change to the question, Now if I access the hello2 method from different js files, then I can't declare multiple objects in my js2 file to access those global variable. I found that in my JS2.js in method `hello2()` i can access the previous function object by `this.hello2.caller` gives me caller method object. But I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: Congratulations, you've changed the question such that my answer no longer makes any sense.  It should come as no surprise that I find this a bit frustrating / annoying.

Next time please acknowledge that your original question was answered (by accepting the answer) and then either 1) create a new question, or 2) just ask your follow-up question in comments.

Comment: And for the record, as you've discovered `caller` only gives you a reference to the calling function.  But there's no built-in mechanism for discovering the context in which a variable is defined from the variable itself, so this isn't helpful for doing what you want.

To do what you're asking - get a reference to the calling module context - you would need to set that explicitly on the function (e.g. `hello1.context = module.exports'`).  But that gets kind of weird.  Instead, just pass it as an argument to `hello2`.